# Could declaration of pointers to derived types be undefined?

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I have a small code declaring a pointer to array of derived type which has a field that is an allocatable array of another derived type having a real variable as a field.
Using gnu fortran (8.2) I obtain different results for each location in the array or as a vector.

Using intel fortran (2019.4) compiler succeeded.

```
program test
implicit none
integer, parameter :: length = 2
real(8), dimension(length) :: a, b
integer :: i

type point
   real(8) :: x
end type point

type stored
   type(point), dimension(:), allocatable :: np
end type stored

type(stored), dimension(:), pointer :: std=>null()


allocate(std(1))
allocate(std(1)%np(length))
std(1)%np(1)%x = 0.3d0
std(1)%np(2)%x = 0.3555d0

do i = 1, length
   write(*, "('std(1)%np(',i1,')%x = ',1e22.14)") i, std(1)%np(i)%x
end do
do i = 1, length
   write(*, "('std(1)%np(1:',i1,') = ',2e22.14)") i, std(1)%np(1:i)%x
end do
a = std(1)%np(1:2)%x
b = [std(1)%np(1)%x, std(1)%np(2)%x]
if (norm2(a - b) .gt. 1d-3) then
   write(*,*) 'failure'
else
   write(*, *) 'success'
end if
end program test
```

the code terminates successfully, but using gfortran one obtains 'failure' on screen and inconsistent prints above and using Intel compiler one obtains 'success' on screen and consistent prints above.

Comment: Attaching the option "-fsanitize=address -g" for gfortran may be useful because it gives a runtime error with the source line (where a memory issue occurs, pointing to the line std(1)%np(1:2)%x). On my machine, using gfortran-4.9 or 5 (or using allocatable instead of pointer for "std") removes the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem presented in the code above was resolved in the following [link] https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=91077

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear to me what your question is, unless it's the title. If so, no, pointers to derived types are fine. Your program correctly allocates std as an extent-1 array and then allocates std(1)%np(2). It then assigns to the x subcomponents of both np elements. Looks fine to me.

There are several things that could potentially cause "failure" - you should run the gfortran code in the debugger to see what is going wrong.

Comment: I see that you also posted this on comp.lang.fortran where it was acknowledged as a gfortran bug.

Comment: Thanks, Steve. Surely, it has been opened as a gfortran bug. It is treated by gfortran developers. One can follow [link](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=91077)